# modify a git branch on a working script without overwriting last version

Tags: git

I've recently started using git for version control in my Python scripts (using both git, via magit, and Python in emacs) and I am not sure I understand how to properly branch.

Suppose I make a script called test.py and this is committed to the master branch of my git repository.  This script may work fine, but I need to make some substantial changed (e.g. go to a version 2.0 for master.py).  Now, test.py is important in that it is continually used in cron jobs, so I want to make sure that while I am working on test.py 2.0 I can continue to call the original.

What I think I should do is branch off of master (call the new branch "version2") and continue to work on the updates.  However, what I have noticed is that when I save test.py under the version2 branch I overwrite the saved version of test.py on disk (i.e. now my cron job will call the not-finished version 2 of test.py)  Does that make sense?

My question is: Can I continue to work on test.py under the version2 branch without overwriting the test.py script that is being called by my cron job?  I guess I do not know how to handle this situation.

Comment: Just deploy your "working" version in another directory, to be called by `cron`. It should not directly execute something in your working tree.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably not call automatically a file that you develop on. One way to resolve your problem is to use `git worktree` to have a separate worktree for your `version2` branch, leaving your `master` worktree that is called by your cron job untouched.

Comment: That makes sense.  I really like the functionality of branching, and don't like the idea of creating a new directory via worktree.  That being said, the new worktree seems to do what I need.  Are you saying that branching will not work here?

Comment: No I don't, you create a branch you are working on and check this out in the newly added worktree. You cannot checkout the same branch in two different worktrees of the same repository. So you will still work on a branch, just not in the main worktree of your repository, but in a second linked one.

Comment: Ok. I have a couple questions: 1. creating a new worktree automatically creates a new branch, right?  Or MUST I first create a new branch then create the worktree off of that?  2.  Can I merge the new worktree back onto the master branch of the original?

Comment: I guess a third question would be: Am I just going about this the wrong way?  I am completely self-taught at programming, so I have missed out on a lot of the "good practices" lessons that would help avoid doing things stupidly.

Comment: **1.** it can, but it doesn't have to. look at its man page. You can tell it which branch to checkout, you can tell it which branch to create from which branch or HEAD, you can let it auto-create a new branch from HEAD or you can tell it to be in detached HEAD state, not creating a new branch. **2.** Don't confuse branches and worktrees. You do not do cloning, you just create a second worktree on the same local repository. So you can work with all branches in all worktrees. You just cannot checkout the same branch at the same time in two different worktrees, so the answer is yes.

Comment: **3.** Maybe it would be better to not work on the productive deployment directly. Work in your own local cloned repository, then instantiate some deployment process. If you want to solve the deployment step with Git (which is not a deployment tool), you can use http://gitolite.com/deploy.html for help with that.

Answer (score 0):

Your assumption that you need to branch off is correct. This will mean you can have two versions of the file and you can use them as and when you need to. After making your changes to `test.py` you can create a new branch by using `git checkout -b [new branch name]`. If you need to go back to the original version, just checkout master again (`git checkout master`).

Once you're happy with your changes in the new version of the file and are now ready to overwrite the original you can merge that branch into master:

```
git checkout master
git merge [new branch]
git branch -D [new branch] --this deletes the 'version 2' branch assuming you no longer need it.
```

Comment: Thanks.  However, even after branching off, test.py will continue to change on disk even before I merge the two branches, right?  I want to make sure I am branching correctly here.

Comment: Yes, you are right, this does not help you as your cron job would still call the wrong file while you are in the other branch. @mohammedkhan, it is better to use `-d` instead of `-D`. `-d` will refuse to delete a branch if it is not merged. `-D` will always delete the branch and thus loose commits that were only on that branch when the reflog is expired and the automatic `git gc` is done. Besides that your answer does not help for the question that was stated.

Comment: I suppose it wouldn't work if you don't have any kind of releasing strategy, I guess I didn't get that from the original question.